# sizeof wont show real size, trying to implement ip

Tags: c++, struct, ip, sizeof

im having a struct to represent an ip header

```
struct IPHDR // the ip header
{
    unsigned char VER : 4;
    unsigned char IHL : 4;
    unsigned char DSCP : 6;
    unsigned char ECN : 2;
    unsigned short len;
    unsigned short id;
    u_char Reserved:1; //Zeroes
    u_char DF:1; //Dont Fragment
    u_char MF:1; //More Fragment
    unsigned short FragOffset : 13;
    u_char ttl;
    u_char protocol;
    u_short checksum;
    struct in_addr src;
    struct in_addr dst;
} ;
```

sizeof(IPHDR) returns 24 when it should return 20.
what is wrong?

Comment: This is because your structure gets padded. If supported you could use a `#pragma pack` directive to overcome this. Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322439/what-is-the-smallest-size-i-can-make-this-structure-on-a-64bit-machine/8322469#8322469

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your structure gets padded to overcome this you could use a [#pragma pack compiler directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) like so:

```
#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)
struct IPHDR // the ip header
{
   unsigned char VER : 4;
   unsigned char IHL : 4;
   unsigned char DSCP : 6;
   unsigned char ECN : 2;
   unsigned short len;
   unsigned short id;
   u_char Reserved:1; //Zeroes
   u_char DF:1; //Dont Fragment
   u_char MF:1; //More Fragment
   unsigned short FragOffset : 13;
   u_char ttl;
   u_char protocol;
   u_short checksum;
   struct in_addr src;
   struct in_addr dst;
 } ;
 #pragma pack(pop)
```

Read more about padding and alignment: [Data structure alignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

this is because of your structure being forced to [memory alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment). In short total size of the structure should be a multiple of the largest alignment of any structure member. This requirement comes from the fact that processors read memory in *word* chunks, not single bytes. Some people say memory allignment is a limitation of modern processors, it could usually be worked around by doing 4 inefficient single byte fetches rather than one efficient word fetch, but many language specifiers decided it would be easier just to outlaw them and force everything to be aligned.

Usually by reimplementing sequence of fields in your structure you can achieve different alignment and size of your structure.

from the link provided:

> It is possible to change the alignment of structures to reduce the
>   memory they require (or to conform to an existing format) by
>   reordering structure members or changing the compiler’s alignment (or
>   “packing”) of structure members.